# Can't get Insider Preview builds for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-insider

I successfully installed a Windows 10 Education Insider Preview image onto my machine. Now, I'm getting notifications telling me I need to change my settings. When I click on them, I see this screen:[image: Fix me screen]

I have a pulse, so I click on "Fix me." Then I get this banner: [image: Privacy settings banner]

And hit confirm. Once I do that, the screen briefly shows a loading sign, then returns to the "Get Insider Preview builds" screen with no change. I've checked the registry settings in [this article](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10240-not-appearing-on-windows-update/), and they appear to be correct. My "Feedback & Diagnostics" settings screen looks like I'd expect:[image: Feedback & Diagnostics screen]

So I'm pretty much out of ideas. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? I'm currently installing new builds by downloading the ISOs and installing manually from there.

Comment: What build are you using exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound 14372 (I'm not in the fast ring)

Comment: get a newer Preview ISO (14388), mount the iso, run setup and select upgrade to update to lastest build

Comment: @magicandre1981 As I mentioned ("I'm currently installing new builds by downloading the ISOs and installing manually from there."), this is how I'm currently updating. However, I don't want to have to do that every time there's an update available. Is there a specific fix in build 14388 that you think would solve this problem when the last few updates I applied this way haven't?

Comment: This installation connected to a domain by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound No, it's not connected to a domain.

Comment: do you use any tweaking tool to stop "spying" of Windows 10?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did, but disabled it when checking for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your Tool to stop the "spying of Windows 10" damaged the Insider Preview settings completely.

Format the PC with the latest ISO you have and don't run any "stop windows 10 spying" tool again. Now Windows Update should offer your the latest [Build 14390](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/07/15/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14390-for-pc-and-mobile/)

Comment: There's no other way to undo it?

Comment: OK, I'll try it in the next few days and get back to you. Thanks!